# Cannot show the new line in label

Tags: javascript, jquery, vb.net

Hi I have a code using vb.net. I need to get the text in the textbox as a parameter for calling javascript function which set the text in the label on the parent page. I replace the new line with `<br/>`. But it still show the `<br/>`on the label. Would someone tell me what to solve it. Thanks in advance.

The text in the textbox:

```
test [ \ ^ $ . | ? * + ( )'
new line
```

The text shows in the parent label:

```
test [ ^ $ . | ? * + ( )'<br/>new line
```

There is my code int vb.net

```
Dim script as string="" 
Dim strText As String = txtNote.Text.Trim.Replace("'", "\'")
strText = strText.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br/>")
script = "window.parent.showNote('" & Server.HtmlEncode(strText) &  "');"
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me.Page, Me.Page.[GetType](), "EditNote", script, True)
```

There is javascript:

```
function showNote(txt){
      $('#lbl').html(txt);
}
```

Comment: What does `test [ ^ $ . | ? * + ( )'` have to do with this question?

Comment: And where/how is `showNote()` being called?

Comment: @ScottMarcus it is call in RegisterStartupScript.   [ ^ $ . | ? * + ( )'  is the text the user type in the textbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the code and work:

```
Dim script as string="" 
Dim strText As String = txtNote.Text.Trim.Replace("'", "\'")
strText A=Server.HtmlEncode(strText)
strText = strText.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br/>")
script = "window.parent.showNote('" & strText &  "');"
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me.Page, Me.Page.[GetType](), "EditNote", script, True)
```